# Using ubuntu CLI, any alternative for SCREEN command

Tags: ubuntu, command-line-interface, putty

when i start using `screen` command in putty, the putty window starts flickering whenever `backspace` or `tab` is hit.

Also, i want to use multiple terminals like we can do in GUI, so is there anything like screen command that can be used in ubuntu CLI ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu CLI"? You have a local GUI-less Ubuntu installation, or are you `ssh`ìng to a remote Ubuntu server?

Comment: I run VMware player to boot the server and then log into the server using putty.
In VMWare i have local GUI-less ubuntu installed.

Comment: when i use "screen" command in vmware, it works fine.

Comment: I think you only can use multiple putty instances...

Comment: Yeah, working with that now...may be low system configuration might be the reason for that.. having 2gb of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest investigating `tmux`, which is very similar to `screen` but offers some extra functionality not available in the standard `screen` package (vertical split screens for example). It is also reported to be a lot less of a resource hog than `screen`

A quick tutorial can be found here: http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/